# Extract from pattern if present, else keep as-is

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following series:

```
ser = pd.Series(['abc', '(d:affds)', 'trrt'])
```

If an element starts with `(d:)` and ends with `)`, I'd like to extract what's inside. Else, I'd like to keep it as-is.

If I do

```
ser.str.extract(r'\(d:(.*)\)')
```

then I get

```
       0
0    NaN
1  affds
2    NaN
```

So, the extraction worked fine for row 1. However, for rows 0 and 2, I'd like to keep the row as-is. So, my expected output is:

```
       0
0    abc
1  affds
2   trrt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `fillna`

```
ser.str.extract(r'\(d:(.*)\)')[0].fillna(ser)
Out[163]: 
0      abc
1    affds
2     trrt
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: This results in the wrong expected output though: The last entry should be `trrt` and not `abc`

Comment: @HansBambel check the update

Comment: Thanks, but why does is work? Only because the name of the series is "0"?

Comment: @HansBambel fillna is check the index match when pass ser to dataframe